# have i toggled wireframe?

Tags: wireframe

Hi I seem to have toggled wireframe and I can't get out of it or is this wireframe at all? I hit Z and nothing changes

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The most likely culprit is the object draw mode (Properties Window > Object Tab > Display > Maximum Draw Type)

[image]

Set it back to `Textured` if you want to be able to go to textured view (and to `Solid` if not).

Comment: sorry what is "options window"? I cant see it

Comment: The Properties window is where you set materials, textures, render settings, etc. It's by default on the right of the screen. You can see it on the lower right of part the screen in the image above. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Properties_Window

Comment: I think he is using that name for the properties editor window.

Comment: You're right @brasshat, my bad.

Comment: (Options Window > Object Tab > Display > Maximum Draw Type) I cant find this

Comment: how do I add pictures in this comment wondow? i want to ask you something else- thanks by the way this is driving me nuts!

Comment: @Dave Goateze, I don't think you can add pictures to a comment. The next best thing is to post the image you want to use to a website somewhere, and create a link to the location of the image. But in my opinion, rather than asking a question in a comment, it is better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to check is that you have not inadvertently set wireframe as the maximum display type for the object. In  the properties editor, object tab, in the bottom left of the "display" pane is a submenu "Maximum Draw Type". Check to see that this is not set to "wireframe".

This is where it is in my preferred interface setup:

[image]

Comment: yes it was on wire but I put it back to textured and nothing has changed

Comment: ah nice one i toggled z and it changes thank you

Answer (score 3):

For future users that might run into the same issue who may benefit from a visual showing the solution to the issue, I thought I'd add a gif demonstrating the steps as outlined in the previous answers. [image]

Comment: that is great thanks. excellent model too