# I cant use the Z command for wireframe

Tags: rendering, wireframe

I was doing some 3d modeling from a tutorial then when I added a circle I pressed f8 instead of f6 then after that z won't toggle wireframe. What did f8 do? Ctrl z works but didn't undo what ever f8 did.

Comment: F8 tries to reload all Add-ons. Maybe there's one that failed to reload correcly, causing keymaps to be messed up. Have you restarted Blender and tried again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get "Z" to toggle wireframe again, turn *Object > Display > Maximum Draw Type* to **Texture** or **Solid** if it is currently set to **Wire**

[image]

Or for the animated version from user [Timaroberts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15924/timaroberts)

[image]

Sources:[Can't get my model out of wireframe mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12078/cant-get-my-model-out-of-wireframe-mode), GIF from [Have I toggled wireframe?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43364/have-i-toggled-wireframe)